# Преобразование символов в HEX

Tags: c#, конвертация, hex

Есть строка "0800", 4 символа длинной.

Открываю HEX-editor, он мне преобразует эту строку  в "30 38 30 30".
Это коды каждого из символов в строке  "0800", с этим понятно. Не могу понять, как преобразовать строку "0800" в строку "30383030".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать на C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Берём символ, преобразуем в число (код символа), форматируем как шестнадцатиричное число из двух цифр, конкатенируем.

```
string.Concat("0800".Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x2")))
```

P.S. Этот код будет работать верно только для ASCII.

Comment: Хотел бы немного дополнить ответ. В .NET есть специальный класс Conversion с перегрузками метода HEX, конечно он работает только с одиночным параметром, но пусть будет: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualbasic.conversion.hex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @z668 Неймспейс VB — это не круто. :)

Comment: .NET он  и есть .NET)